# Work with extjs controller

Tags: extjs

I have a question regarding ExtJS controllers. My code:

```
Ext.define('app.controller.Clients.Clients', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['Clients.Clients'],
    models: ['Clients.Clients'],
    views: ['Clients.Clients'],
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'gridClients button[action=deleteClient]': {
                click: this.onButtonClickDelete
            },
            'gridClients button[action=refreshClients]': {
                click: this.onButtonClickRefresh
            },
            'gridClients button[action=printClients]': {
                click: this.onButtonClickPrint
            }
        })
    },
    onButtonClickDelete: function(button, e, options) {
        alert('DELETE?');
    },
    onButtonClickRefresh: function(button, e, options) {
        alert('REFRESH?');
    },
    onButtonClickPrint: function(button, e, options) {
        alert('PRINT?');
    }
});
```

I'm going to refer to a grid named 'gridClients', and I'd like to know if there is any way to create a variable inside the driver file...

I'm going to refer to a grid named 'gridClients', and I would like to know if there is any way to create a variable inside the driver file, to refer to that grid.

Example, I would like something similar to:

```
Var Grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query (#gridClients) [0];
```

And use it like this:

```
OnButtonClickRefresh: function (button, e, options) {
         Grid.getStore (). Load ();
     }
```

I really do not know where to declare that var...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a controller, you are expected to work with the [`refs`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.app.Controller.html#cfg-refs). Example:

```
Ext.define('app.controller.Clients.Clients', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['Clients.Clients'],
    models: ['Clients.Clients'],
    views: ['Clients.Clients'],
    init: function() {
        ...
    },
    refs:[{
        ref:'clientsGridExample',
        selector: '#gridClients'
    }],
    OnButtonClickRefresh: function (button, e, options) {
         this // inside a controller, these functions are scoped to controller
             .getClientsGridExample() // refs are automatically converted to getter methods
             .getStore().load(); // Do whatever you want to do
    }
});
```

Comment: Great!
It works, thanks for showing me the use of 'refs', after reading the documentation a bit, I understand its use.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear, if you check the [Ext.app.Controller documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.app.Controller.html#ext-app-controller_using-refs).

You can set `refs` in your controller and use generated getter to get the grid you need. For example, if you have `ref` with value `clientsGrid`, getter `getClientsGrid()` will be created by ExtJS.

`

```
Ext.define('app.controller.Clients.Clients', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['Clients.Clients'],
    models: ['Clients.Clients'],
    views: ['Clients.Clients'],

    refs: [
        { ref: 'grid', selector: '#gridClients' }
    ],    

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'gridClients button[action=deleteClient]': {
                click: this.onButtonClickDelete
            },
            'gridClients button[action=refreshClients]': {
                click: this.onButtonClickRefresh
            },
            'gridClients button[action=printClients]': {
                click: this.onButtonClickPrint
            }
        })
    },
    onButtonClickDelete: function(button, e, options) {
        this.getGrid().doSomething();
    },
    onButtonClickRefresh: function(button, e, options) {
        alert('REFRESH?');
    },
    onButtonClickPrint: function(button, e, options) {
        alert('PRINT?');
    }
});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the OnButtonClickRefresh listener you can get the grid like this:

```
var grid = button.up("grid");
```

Link to the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1v4c)